# edit message sent in last step in wizard | telegraf-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, telegram-bot, telegraf

How can I edit the message sent in the `getMessage` function at `sendToAdmin` function?

- telegraf-js v4.4.1
- typescript

```js
async function getMessage(ctx: Context) {
  // message
  await ctx.editMessageText("text");

  return (<any>ctx).wizard.next();
}

async function sendToAdmin(ctx: Context) {
    
  // edit here

  return (<any>ctx).wizard.leave();
}

const superWizard = new Scenes.WizardScene(
  getMessage,
  sendToAdmin
);
```

Comment: your question is not clear add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Context.wizard.state`

```js
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TOKEN);

async function getMessage(ctx: Context) {

  // message have message id
  const message = await ctx.editMessageText("text");

  // send message id to wizard
  // for use in next step
  (<any>ctx).wizard.state.message = { message: message.message_id };

  return (<any>ctx).wizard.next();
}

async function sendToAdmin(ctx: Context) {
    
  // use here
  const lastMessageID = (<any>ctx).wizard.state.message.message;

  // edit last message
  bit.telegram.editMessageText(ctx.from.id, lastMessageID, "EDIT_TEXT")

  return (<any>ctx).wizard.leave();
}
```